# Find a generators for the following ideal in R[X]

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

$$I =\langle x^5+x^3+x^2-1, x^5+x^3+x^2 \rangle$$

I am struggling with this exercise as I have been given definition for ideals but no worked examples. I have also struggled to find any examples online that are clear to me. If possible could i have the method to solving such a question explained to me and what the question is asking for?

Comment: Hint:  $x^5+x^3+x^2- (x^5+x^3+x^2-1)=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the polynomial ring over a field is a P.I.D., the ideal generated by a family of elements is generated  by a g.c.d. of these elements.

You can easily find $\gcd(x^5+x^3+x^2-1, x^5+x^3+x^2)$.

Comment: If i am not mistaken the gcd=1. Does that mean the generator of I is 1 ?

Comment: Yes. These two polynomials are coprime, so they generate the whole ring of polynomials.

Comment: Is this the only one generator? if there are more how do i find them?

Comment: Any unit in $R$ will be a generator. Working in $\mathbf Z$, this means, you might as well take $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Ideals have several properties:

1. **An ideal is an additive subgroup of the ring.** Therefore if an ideal contains $P$ and $Q$ it will contain $P+Q$ as well as $P-Q$. With $P=x^5+x^3+x^2$ and $Q=x^5+x^3+x^2-1$ you have $P-Q=1$. Therefore 
   $$1\in I$$
2. **An ideal is closed under multiplication by elements of the ring.** This means that if $P\in R[X]$ and $Q\in I$ then $PQ\in I$. Applying this to *any* $P$ and $Q=1$ you get: $P\in I$ for all $P$, in other words
   $$R[X]\subset I$$
3. **An ideal is a subset of the ring.** Therefore, $$I\subset R[X]$$

Altogether, $I=R[X].$